# Prometheus Integration with Node-Problem-Dectector which IP to assign for Prometheus Exporter?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

While integrating node-prometheus-detector with prometheus what is the prometheus-exporter IP address? Is it the Prometheus Node Exporter which also listens on port 9100? Can you please provide me an example of how to integrate node-problem-detector with Prometheus-Operator?

Comment: I was unaware of [Node Problem Detector] (https://github.com/kubernetes/node-problem-detector) until I read your question. It looks useful and I will start using it, thanks. It appears you can configure Prometheus export using the command-line flags described [here] (https://github.com/kubernetes/node-problem-detector#for-prometheus-exporter)

Comment: There's a default port (`20257`). You'll likely need to create a PodMonitor or ServiceMonitor for Prometheus Operator to be notified about its metrics.

Comment: Interesting Thank you will try that out and let you know @DazWilkin

Comment: Can you use this Helm chart :
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/deliveryhero/node-problem-detector   
here it wants us to pass the prometehus exporter address. Due to Prometheus-Node-Exporter also using same ports we are not able to bind the IP's. Can you try this chart? Please advise

Comment: DazWilkin could you please or provide me a reference for ServiceMonitor or Pod Monitor have never set it up.. Thank you 

Comment: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md#servicemonitor and https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md#podmonitor

Comment: So If I understand correctly I need to create a Service and ServiceMonitor for Node Problem Detector and provide Prometheus App details. Only thingwhat is confusing is the named port requirement!